# Is there a way by which I can uninstall a specific update to an app?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, updates, uninstallation

I have an app, Uber, that is taking up huge space on my phone. It cannot be moved to sd card.

Recently, they've launched an update of size 21MB. I'm afraid of the fact that, every time there is a new update, the size of the app increases. I know that I can uninstall all updates of an app from settings, but is it possible to uninstall a specific update of an app? I'm asking because if I find the update useless, I'll uninstall that specific update only.

It is preferable that the process does not require rooting. I'm working on Samsung Galaxy On7, Android 6.0.1-Marshmallow.

Comment: You cannot uninstall only a specific update, as you have no knowledge of what the update has changed. Plus, even if feasible, it would be useless, as the most new update would always install the content of the previous updates. In short, you cannot choose what to keep and what to throw away.

Comment: As I understand you think that whenever update is released for some app the size of app is increased for a size of update. Well that isn't the case (it can happen randomly but it not always like that). Some apps that are poorly designed when updating just download whole apk and install, but some get let say patch so it doesn't download whole app again, but app size doesn't increase for an size of update. And answer to your question you can't select what update to install to an app and that's it it doesn't need explaining because apps are made to be like that.